# SPI design with different speed

Tags: spi

I am studying SPI communication protocol and its design in VIVADO environment. I have found here a big discussion topics about SPI and topics([1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445475/multiplexing-low-speed-spi-slaves-with-a-high-speed-spi-master-time-division),[2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69600/synchronizing-spi-ports-for-higher-data-rate)) which are "covered" my questions:

1. What are differences between high and low speed SPI?

please, guys. I know what high or low speed mean. I need some information about design/ implementation differences or smth else

2. Does "speed" mean a data rate of input data in this contest?

Comment: The only difference is that very high speeds will need much more PCB layout and EMC care.

Comment: This sounds like you are in the middle of a quiz. We won't do your quiz for you. We expect you to do a substantial amount of work yourself, then ask only a specific question.

Comment: Hint: What is the difference between a high speed car and a low speed car? Does speed mean a rate of distance traveled per hour in this context?

Comment: SPI standard doesn't speak about speed unlike I2C, UART ...

Comment: @Lundin "... much more PCB layout and EMC care..." Could you please give some explaantion?

Answer (score 1):

1. No difference. Except for the speed because it's being specifically mentioned.
2. Yes, most likely the speed only means the data rate in your context.

So in general, there are no special high or low speed modes in SPI.

Comment: 1. i heard that low speed SPI is a question of software, a high speed is hardware.... 2. If there is no difference, we could use the same implementation for low and high data rate transmission. right?

Comment: 1) Where did you hear this? We can't comment whether that source is right or wrong and whether your understanding of the source is right or wrong. 2) Not necessarily, it depends on the details what is meant by low and high speed since you clearly have some definitions what is classified as high speed or low speed and we don't know what definitions you use. SPI is SPI regardless of speed. Different implementations can affect how high speeds are possible.

Comment: What is a difference between SPI stream and SPI memory mapped? are they designed differently?

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva that has nothing to do with SPI bus itsef, that relates how a CPU logically sees an external memory chip as memory that just happens to be physically connected with SPI bus, and the interface between CPU and the SPI bus needs to be different. But that is another question, if you have new questions then start a new question.